# What is the difference between reverse-proxy and load-balancer in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

**TCP server**

```
import socket
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.bind(('0.0.0.0', 5010))
s1.listen(1)
c1 = s1.accept()
```

**Nginx load-balance config**

```
stream {
    upstream lbc {
        server localhost:5010;
        server localhost:5020;
    }
    server {
        listen 8090;
        proxy_pass lbc;
    }
}
```

**curl command**

```
curl localhost:8090
```

**netstat output**

```
$> sudo netstat -nalp | egrep "5010|8090"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5010            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43545/python3
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      38059/nginx: master
tcp       78      0 127.0.0.1:5010          127.0.0.1:44000         ESTABLISHED 43545/python3
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8090          127.0.0.1:39488         ESTABLISHED 43367/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44000         127.0.0.1:5010          ESTABLISHED 43367/nginx: worker
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39488         127.0.0.1:8090          ESTABLISHED 43546/curl
```

Next I replaced Nginx load-balance config with Nginx reverse proxy-config shown below and ran the curl command. I see similar netstat output (except the ports are different). I don't see any change in the forwarding mechanism by Nginx.

**Nginx reverse-proxy config**

```
http {
    upstream lbc {
        server localhost:5010;
        server localhost:5020;
    }
    server {
        listen 8090;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://lbc;
        }
    }
}
```

So what is the difference between reverse-proxy and load-balancing?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Proxy is used with a single infrastructure web/app server, typically. Load balancing is used with multiple web/app servers on the backend. They both have pros/cons and depending on the deployment scenario, one is better than the other.